# For i loop running infinitely React Native

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, loops

I am currently writing an app in React Native and in it I have some save files stored in an array. In the code below, I loop through these saves and create a JSON version of the data ready to be transferred into XML using a separate function. The problem is that the code works, but runs infinitely and rather than creating a few buttons, creates a never ending amount (I have attached a screenshot). Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have been stuck on this for days and have tried everything!

```
export function sessionsViewer({ navigation, route }) {

  const [dataResults, setDatResults] = useState({ type: "View", children: [{}] })

  async function getDataResults() {
    var previousSaves = await getDataJSON('saves')
    for(let i = 0; i < previousSaves.length; i++){
      let prevSave = previousSaves[i]
      let json = {
        'type': 'View',
        'children': [
          {
            'type': 'Touchable',
            'styles': [styles.startButton, { width: widthPercentageToDP(90) }],
            'onpress': () => { alert('You pressed me!' + JSON.stringify(prevSave.scores)) },
            'children': [
              {
                'type': 'Text',
                'text': prevSave.technique + ': ' + prevSave.datetime,
                'styles': styles.buttonTXT
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
      let prevDataResults = dataResults
      prevDataResults.children.push(json)
      setDatResults({ ...prevDataResults })
    }
  }
```

[Image showing infinite list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuhZL.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a global boolean variable like `let control = false;`. And set true before calling setDatResults.

```
control = true;
setDatResults({ ...prevDataResults })
control = false;
```

If we control this variable at the beginning of getDataResults function.
This prevents the infinite loop.

```
async function getDataResults() {
    if (control) {
       return;
    }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I have tried it but it did not seem to work so I implemented the variable as a React hook and that did the job better but instead of an infinite loop it now is only duplicated. I expect there to be two buttons as I have two saves but instead there are four. Do know of any reason why it might be doing this?

Comment: Could you try to put "setDatResults({ ...prevDataResults })" to out of "for loop" (after loop) and put "let prevDataResults = dataResults" to before "for loop" ?

Comment: Hello, I tried that but it did not work but I have managed to fix it now by passing it all in a useEffect. Thanks for all the help!